# git status produce no output

Tags: git, ssh, putty

Why would git status not produce any output?
When I am using it, it just waits for additional input. I have to cancel it as some point using CTRL-C.

Other git commands (eg git log) works just fine.
On the same repository but on another computer, it works just fine.

NB : I am working from a distant location through putty to connect to a gate server, and from there, I ssh to my working station.

Comment: I am stuck on the troubleshooting, any suggestion is welcome

Comment: `strace git status` should tell what is running behind the scenes and what does it wait for.

Comment: Waw I didn't know about strace. I am getting hundreds of messages like this
`read(3, "\370\300\271\375~+8)8\37\3\307z\36fY<\336\353O\34\344\364\360u)[\354\"\222\335\301"..., 16384) = 16384`

Comment: It doesn't help without context. Either post whole log or try to find the relevant parts yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually working fine. Due to a very large file (2gb), git status takes an insanely long time.
There is then two solutions :

1) remove the file, or add it to the gitignore

2) use git options to stop checking if the file has been modified

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [<file> ...]
```

To do the opposite in case the file needs to be updated on the repo :

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [<file> ...]
```

Comment: Another option would be to add the file to `.gitignore`.